# Talend dynamic schema

Tags: talend

I need to create a job in which I have to read from a DB table and write into another DB table. I have to do this operation for almost 20 tables. So is there a way to do it dynamically instead of creating the same job for each table? My SGBD is Oracle. I now that we can loop over all needed table either via a toracleRow query or via tOracleTableList. And we can also get the list of columns also via an a tOracleRow sql query and then iterate over the column list. Now the difficulty is how to use the tSetDynamicSchema or other solution to create the schema dynamically in the tOracle input and in the tOracleOutput.

Any idea is welcome.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Enterprise version can do this via Dynamic schema: https://help.talend.com/reader/r6c1eibADl1LPk5tkVvJ2g/g3YdShPoJku~sTqehUFSBA

This could be used to link an input and an output together. Tables could be created automatically etc.

In open studio you can't do this unless you write the Java code by yourself.